# Vectorization of complex vector multiplication using interleaved data format in C/C++

Tags: c, vectorization, fft, real-time

I am working on performing a complex multiplication between two arrays in C. The values are stored in an interleaved float format with real values at uneven indices and complex values at even indices. I want to speed up the computation by vectorizing the multiplication. Background: The code has to run in realtime and is part of an fast FFT convolution in frequency domain between signal X and H.

Below you see some code. It runs not as fast as I would need it (around 400us at the moment for Y_N = 2^16 on i7-8750H).

Can you give me some hint how I can further speed up the "for loop"?

```
// dimension
long Y_N;
long Y_Ncpx = 2 * Y_N;

// free memory for interleaved float array containing complex data (real, imaginary, real, imaginary, ....
float *X = (float*)malloc(Y_Ncpx * sizeof(float));
float *H = (float*)malloc(Y_Ncpx * sizeof(float));
float *Y = (float*)malloc(Y_Ncpx * sizeof(float));
// fill in data

// caculate complex multiplication between X array and H array and save in Y array (How do we vectorize those part?)
long nreal;
long nimag;
for (long n = 0; n < Y_N; n++) {
    nreal = 2 * n;
    nimag = nreal + 1;
    Y[nreal] = X[nreal] * H[nreal] - X[nimag] * H[nimag]; // real part
    Y[nimag] = X[nreal] * H[nimag] + X[nimag] * H[nreal]; // imaginary part
}
```

Comment: Why not use the standard complex number types?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with C, but using 'restrict' on the pointers might help the compiler. Also, without seeing the output assembly its hard to know exactly what the compiler is doing. Is it generating the vector instructions for 4 (or 8) floats? Multiplication inside the for loop is also unnecessary. Use `n+=2` in your loop header, then `nreal = n; nimag = nreal+1`, which might give a little bit more out of it, but doubtful.

Comment: This looks like pure C. Why is it tagged "C++"? They are *very* different languages.

Comment: Your text says the real components are at “uneven” indices and the “complex” (presumably imaginary) components are at even indices, but your code shows the real index `nreal` being set to even values and the imaginary index `nimag` being set to odd values.

Comment: There are existing libraries for perform complex array multiplication, such as BLAS/LAPACK and, on macOS, the Accelerate framework. Generally, you should use these libraries and not write your own code for this, as it is quite labor intensive. Is there a reason you are not using existing libraries?

Comment: If you use a C++ compiler, tag as C++. If you use a C compiler, tag as C. These are different languages with different things to consider. Please [edit] your tags accordingly.

Comment: Interleaved complex multiplication is possible to vectorize, but unnecessary complex (no pun intended). You should consider storing the data de-interleaved while working with it and only interleave the final result (if required).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @ChrisMM thanks for the hint with the +=2, good point!

Comment: @EricPostpischil The code is written as much as possible in native c as it should be cross platform compatible to windows/android/ios/unix, so adding the libraries you noted is an option in case portability can be ensured.

Comment: @chtz how would you write a complex multiplication for loop with higher speed in case the data would be stored non-interleaved?

Comment: @pffelix If you just replace the indexing with `nreal = n; nimag=n+Y_N` gcc generates nicely vectorized code: https://godbolt.org/z/e4R7mS For clang you need to additionally pass `-ffast-math` if you want to have FMA instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/9X-0tT

Comment: For a cross-platform FFT, you should consider FFTW. Implementing high-performance FFTs is a complicated task requiring a variety of skills and knowledge. Optimal implementations depend on SIMD features, specific instruction timings, cache geometry, and more. Focusing on a complex vector multiplication is a mistake; a high-performance FFT needs to be engineered on several levels.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Intel MKL is used for calculting the fourier transformation. The multiplication is done for fast convolution in frequency domain of two transformed FFt signals.

Comment: @chtz thanks for the hint. Very helpful. Also the website.

Comment: @chtz Do you have any idea how to quickly transform the interleaved storage (returned from the FFT) to a storage format containing a block of real and a block of complex values such that the vectorization speed up can be done with a performance gain?

Comment: My suggestion would mostly be useful, if you could make the FFT work with de-interleaved complexes. De-interleaving, multiplying and re-interleaving is most likely not worth the effort.

Comment: @chtz: (Aside: An FFT implementation can fairly readily accommodate interleaved data by semideinterleaving it during the first pass and reinterleaving it during the last pass. By semideinterleaving, I mean reading two SIMD blocks’ worth of alternating data (RIRIRIRI), deinterleaving just those two blocks get get RRRR and IIII in two registers, doing the initial butterfly calculations, and writing the two blocks, RRRR and IIII. Then all internal FFT operations can be done with SIMD code on homogeneous blocks, until the final stages.)

Comment: Since you are using Intel MKL, is not `vcMul` the routine you want for element-wise multiplication of two vectors of single-precision complex numbers?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just checked the documentation of Intel MKL vcMul() and it seems promising. I will integrate it to speed up the code.